# Multi-objective problem with non-primitive types in Jenetics

Tags: java, optimization, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

I would like to implement a multi-objective knapsack problem with two knapsacks in Jenetics, but I struggle with some typing issues. I had a look at the `DTLZ1` problem from the [Jenetics manual](http://jenetics.io/manual/manual-4.3.0.pdf)—which is to my knowledge the only MOO example available—and mapped it to the [`Problem`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/4.3/index.html) class:

```
public class DTLZ1 implements Problem<double[], DoubleGene, Vec<double[]>> {

    // Constants...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Engine setup and evolution stream execution...
    }

    @Override
    public Function<double[], Vec<double[]>> fitness() {
        // Original fitness function...
    }

    @Override
    public Codec<double[], DoubleGene> codec() {
        // Original codec...
    }

}
```

I have previously implemented a [single-objective knapsack problem in Scala](https://gist.github.com/beatngu13/1c78bc46ec5c47bcc8bb3da32ab8fcfd#file-jeneticsexample-scala) using the following type signature (converted to Java):

```
Problem<ISeq<BitGene>, BitGene, Integer>
```

Where:

- `<ISeq<BitGene>`: a knapsack as a (immutable) sequence of bits.
- `BitGene`: the gene type of the evolution engine.
- `Integer`: the fitness of the knapsack, i.e., its profit.

Using two knapsacks, I thought about something like (based on the `DTLZ1` example):

```
Problem<ISeq<BitGene>[], BitGene, Vec<int[]>>
```

Where:

- `ISeq<BitGene>[]`: multiple knapsacks as (immutable) sequences of bits, wrapped in an array.
- `BitGene`: the gene type of the evolution engine (same as above).
- `int[]`: the fitness of the knapsacks, i.e., their profit.

Apart from `ISeq<BitGene>[]`, which takes some time getting used to (could I also use `List` or something similar?), I don't know how to create a proper codec:

```
@Override
public Codec<ISeq<BitGene>[], BitGene> codec() {
    return Codecs.ofVector(
            () -> {
                // What kind of supplier do I need?
            },
            NUMBER_OF_KNAPSACKS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the codec would look like this:

```
public static <T> Codec<ISeq<ISeq<T>>, BitGene>
codec(final ISeq<? extends T> items, final int knapsackCount) {
    return Codec.of(
        Genotype.of(
            BitChromosome.of(items.length()).instances()
                .limit(knapsackCount)
                .collect(ISeq.toISeq())
        ),
        gt -> gt.stream()
            .map(ch -> ch.as(BitChromosome.class))
            .map(ch -> ch.ones()
                .<T>mapToObj(items)
                .collect(ISeq.toISeq()))
            .collect(ISeq.toISeq())
    );
}
```

Instead of an `ISeq<T>[]` array, I'm using a `ISeq<ISeq<T>>`, but the size of the first sequence will be `knapsackCount` and the size of the nested sequence is `itmes.length()`. The signature of your problem will be `Problem<ISeq<ISeq<T>>, BitGene, Vec<double[]>>`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Is there a reason why you made the inner type generic instead of `BitGene` (i.e. `ISeq<ISeq<BitGene>>`)? And I don't get the second `map`, respectively, the `mapToObj`.

Comment: I think this encoding is nearer to your problem domain. But you easily use a sequence of bit-genes, just replace the second `map` call, `ch.ones().mapToObj(items)`, with `.map(BitChromosome::toSeq)`.